# Aba atividades de um usuário específico emite 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Ao acessar a aba https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/522/nmindz?tab=activity&sort=all no perfil do [@nmindz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/522/nmindz) visualizo a seguinte página:

[image: resultado]

No console:

[image: console]

No caso só notei o problema neste perfil, o @Randrade que notificou sobre o problema parece que é especificamente no perfil, talvez algo com o cache no lado do servidor.

Comment: A gente já sabe quem aprontou arte. Olha o gato ali --^

Comment: @rray se fosse um cão não teria ocorrido o problema :)

Comment: Aposto minha camiseta do SO que é uma `NullReferenceException` de algum caso que esqueceram de validar =)

Comment: Se a aposta for comigo eu suponho que seja conflito de cache mal implementado do lado back-end, isto ocorre com coisas muito tempo inativas aqui no site =) ... se eu perder te ajudo com teu projeto PHP remotamente :p

Comment: Eu fico fora por milênios e em questão de 15 minutos virei tópico no Meta. Eu já sabia que não era um dos melhores programadores e que meu código parecia ter vida própria, quebrando aleatoriamente, mas agora estou impressionado com o meu potencial de quebrar código sem mesmo ter de tocá-lo. :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Aparentemente foi resolvido. Ou alguém fez algo, ou o cache foi atualizado automaticamente. Eu voto nas 2 opções :p

Comment: @Randrade Me parece que subiram uma atualização

Comment: @jbueno Eu nem sei dizer, nunca guardo o número da rev. atual. kk

Comment: @Randrade É que começa com a data :p

Comment: @jbueno Então subiram antes das 3 da manhã (UTM). Dá medo de alguém subir uma rev uma hora dessas. kkkkkk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A remoção de código que não era mais utilizado causou o problema - nós não percebemos que outras partes do sistema dependiam daquele trecho e isso causou o erro.

Nós restauramos o código e estamos estudando maneiras de remover a parte desnecessária, mas sem causar mais erros.

Obrigado pelo aviso!

> This was caused by the removal of some unused code - the removal had unforeseen dependencies down the line, causing this error.
>
> We have reverted that change and are looking at ways to cleanup the dead code without causing this error.
>
> Thanks for reporting!